# dpc++ start the do loop from 1 to n-2 using parallel_for range

Tags: c++, sycl, dpc++

Is that possible to start the do loop and the index is from 1 to n-2 using dpc++ parallel_for?

```
h.parallel_for(range{lx , ly }, [=](id<2> idx
```

this will give a do loop from 0 to lx-1, and I have to do

```
idx[0]>0 && idx[1]>0 && idx[0]<lx-1 && idx[1]<ly-1
```

and then I can complete the loop?

Also, does dpc++ support like 4D parallel_for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SYCL 1.2.1, `parallel_for` supports offsets, so you could use `h.parallel_for(range{lx-2, ly-2}, id{1, 1}, [=](id<2> idx){ ... });`.

However, this overload [has been deprecated in SYCL 2020](https://www.khronos.org/registry/SYCL/specs/sycl-2020/html/sycl-2020.html#sec:what-changed-between):

> Offsets to `parallel_for`, `nd_range`, `nd_item` and `item` classes have been deprecated. As such, the parallel iteration spaces all begin at `(0,0,0)` and developers are now required to handle any offset arithmetic themselves. The behavior of `nd_item.get_global_linear_id()` and `nd_item.get_local_linear_id()` has been clarified accordingly.

So, if you want to conform to the latest standard, you should apply the offset manually:

`h.parallel_for(range{lx-2, ly-2}, [=](id<2> idx0) { id<2> idx = idx0 + 1; ... });`

That said, depending on your data layout, your original approach of having "empty" threads might be faster.

> Also, does dpc++ support like 4D parallel_for?

No. You will have to use 1D range and compute the 4D index manually.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, can I ask one more question? what is the meaning of the nd_range? I understand that nd_range divided the global array into a local one and does the calculation separately, but what does that mean?

Comment: For most GPU hardware, the work-items (aka "threads" in CUDA) are organized into work-groups (aka "blocks"). Work-items in the same work-group can communicate efficiently with each other (local memory, barriers etc). `sycl::nd_range` allows you to explicitly specify the size of each work-group. If you don't need this in your kernel, then `sycl::range` is just fine.

Comment: Does the `sycl::id` class support addition? I can't find it in the documentation atleast.

Comment: @IPribec it does, see "Table 117. Hidden friend functions of the id class template" in [SYCL2020 rev7](https://registry.khronos.org/SYCL/specs/sycl-2020/html/sycl-2020.html#id-class)